# Reddit Investigator-like JS app

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, api, reddit

I am building a one-page JS app similar to redditinvestigator.com, and my goal is for it to be 100% done in JavaScript. Coming from a PHP/Java background, I'm more used to working in class oriented languages, so I just want to get a sense if I am implementing them correctly in JavaScript.

My code works as expected, and I am just hoping to get some feedback on if there is anything I technically am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do some of the things I am implementing.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZD4U/) (the results are just in the console FYI)

```
var Comment = function(obj) {
    if (obj) {
        this.data = obj.body;
        this.created_utc = obj.created_utc;
        this.downs = obj.downs;
        this.gilded = obj.gilded;
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.link_id = obj.link_id;
        this.link_title = obj.link_title;
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.subreddit = obj.subreddit;
        this.ups = obj.ups;
    }
};


Comment.prototype.getBody = function() {
    return this.data;
};
Comment.prototype.getCreated = function() {
    return this.created_utc;
};
Comment.prototype.getDownvotes = function() {
    return this.downs;
};
Comment.prototype.getUpvotes = function() {
    return this.ups;
};
Comment.prototype.getScore = function() {
    return this.ups - this.downs;
};
Comment.prototype.isGilded = function() {
    return this.gilded;
};
Comment.prototype.getID = function() {
    return this.id;
};
Comment.prototype.getLinkID = function() {
    return this.link_id;
};
Comment.prototype.getLinkTitle = function() {
    return this.link_title;
};
Comment.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
};
Comment.prototype.getSubreddit = function() {
    return this.subreddit;
};



var RedditInterface = function(username) {
    this.userName = username;
    this.commentCount = 0;
    this.submissionCount = 0;
    this.lastCall = 0;
};

RedditInterface.prototype.getUsername = function() {
    return this.userName;
};

RedditInterface.prototype.sendQuery = function(endpoint, after, func) {
    var curDate = new Date().getTime();
    var timeSince = curDate - this.lastCall;
    if (timeSince < 5000)
        return null;
    this.lastCall = curDate;

    var urlD = '';
    if (after === '')
        urlD = "http://www.reddit.com/user/" + this.userName + "/" + endpoint + ".json?limit=100&jsonp=?";
    else
        urlD = "http://www.reddit.com/user/" + this.userName + "/" + endpoint + ".json?limit=100&after=" + after + "&jsonp=?";

    $.ajax({
        url: urlD,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: func
    });
};

RedditInterface.prototype.loadAllComments = function() {
    var here = this;
    var intervalHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
        here.sendQuery('comments', commentAfter, function(data) {
            if (data.data.children.length === 0) { //We've loaded all the comments reddit will give us
                console.log("Comments loaded. Total: " + commentLog.length);
                window.clearInterval(intervalHandle);
            }
            for (var point in data.data.children) {
                var ret = new Comment(data.data.children[point].data);
                var accept = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < commentLog.length; i++) {
                    if (commentLog[i].name == ret.name) {
                        console.log(i + ' (' + commentLog[i].name + ') is equal to current (' + ret.name + '), ommitting.');
                        accept = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (accept && typeof ret.name !== 'undefined') {
                    commentLog.push(ret);
                    commentAfter = ret.name;
                }
            }
            console.log(commentLog);
        });
    }, 5500);
    return intervalHandle;
};

//Begin Logic
var commentLog = [];
var submissionLog = [];
var commentAfter = '';

var ri = new RedditInterface("hueypriest");
var handle = ri.loadAllComments();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very clean, easy to understand and well written. My only comment for improving it would be to take advantage of a framework that does some of this lifting for you, such as:

- KnockoutJS
- BackboneJS
- AngularJS

As well, coming from an OO background, you might be interested at looking at CoffeeScript, which is a higher level language that provides class constructs and such that compiles down into regular JavaScript.